# How to specify HMAC key and message as hexadecimal in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hmac

I have this code in node.js:

```
crypto = require('crypto');

secret  = 'e8f32e723decf4051aefac8e2c93c9c5b214313817cdb01a1494b917c8436b35';
secret2 = 'E8F32E723DECF4051AEFAC8E2C93C9C5B214313817CDB01A1494B917C8436B35';  // upper case

theString  = "800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D";  // upper case
theString2 = "800c28fca386c7a227600b2fe50b7cae11ec86d3bf1fbe471be89827e19d72aa1d";  

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret)
             .update(theString, 'hex')
             .digest('hex');

console.log("HMAC : " + hmac);
```

With secret and theString

```
HMAC = 588cf3e244ae6a6fa3db9761a32f715dc50e080b1b427229654af67e453c3f0d6456975095e32e3c8e68af386e19cb1ef3c1d8b546a8af0279be2fe43bf91c08
```

With secret and theString2

```
HMAC = 588cf3e244ae6a6fa3db9761a32f715dc50e080b1b427229654af67e453c3f0d6456975095e32e3c8e68af386e19cb1ef3c1d8b546a8af0279be2fe43bf91c08
```

hmac is the same => theString is interpreted as hexadecimal

With secret2 and theString

```
HMAC = 1cc29c3b964ac964a960e3d9b82b9db6b4df3cc3675d60e25fdd9dee64672a9ce2dfa86afb25c8684416f88b47f6e16981029574fcc144e4be05114e2c059e23
```

hmac is different => secret is interpreted as a string (ASCII or unicode...)

Question: is there a way to specify secret as hexadecimal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to pass in a binary string, you can always pass in a Buffer:

```
hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(secret, 'hex'))
             .update(new Buffer(theString, 'hex'))
             .digest('hex');
```

According to the documentation [`Hmac#update`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_update_data) doesn't have an encoding option, so don't use an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : REMARK

> According to the documentation Hmac#update doesn't have an encoding
>   option, so don't use an undocumented feature.

-if I DON'T use the option 'hex' in update

with theString

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(secret, 'hex'))
      .update(theString)
hmac = 8df515ab391531d68e5bc29c91fc21771b10dbdf29f24d0eaa92d40a48d8faa2ee432356d72d771d2eb97b2be071b235056df8707327869f0c9830ea5814158b
```

with theString2

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(secret, 'hex'))
      .update(theString2)
hmac = 5ba6e9eaea4e28a9ad197b519ba72d8f5070ac8208dd135ec6adc17cbaa70ed6279c698c95feeaf55b2b936d02f92c05901ff7c786b70c74fb2bb8beefdb6e65
```

the hmac are differents => theString and theString2 are interpreted as string

-if I use the option 'hex' in update

with theString

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(secret, 'hex'))
      .update(theString, 'hex')
hmac = 4135e2908192c404f776a273b0877437417da0605b385ced1cdf0ffe9446877436896baf8f5439848c1c6fa095d1a2fb01ef2a077db58b15fb4ef63dbc92a6e5
```

with theString2

```
crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(secret, 'hex'))
      .update(theString2, 'hex')
hmac = 4135e2908192c404f776a273b0877437417da0605b385ced1cdf0ffe9446877436896baf8f5439848c1c6fa095d1a2fb01ef2a077db58b15fb4ef63dbc92a6e5
```

the hmac are the same => theString and theString2 are interpreted as hexadecimal
    => the option seems valid !!!
but I will use a buffer instead